# Creating POSIX applications in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, posix, sua

So, is POSIX subsystem still around?
I have Visual Studio 2012. I tried to compile a "hello world" Posix application and it seems to be missing the entry point:

> > >cl stuff.cpp /Fostuff.obj /link /subsystem:posix
> >
> > LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __PosixProcessStartup
> >     unlink.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Some Googling shows that I need psxdll.lib and some other libraries, but where are they? Visual Studio does not have them, and neither does the latest Windows SDK. Did they quietly kill the ability to create POSIX apps without telling anyone?

Comment: If you have Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise, you can install the psxdll.dll and friends from the Windows options in your control panel/programs. To get the actual tools to Windows\SUA directory you also need to get the Subsystem for Unix based applications SDK. But where you get the psxdll.lib and friends beats me too as it does not seem to come with Windows SDK 5.0, 6.0, 7.0A, 7.0 nor the Windows Server 2008 SDK. I did find the lib files in MASM32 SDK distribution, but I cannot confirm what version of the PSXDLL.DLL and friends those correspond to.

Answer (score 1):

This requires Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise. A minimal set of Microsoft [Subsystem for Unix-based Applications (SUA)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771470.aspx) is installed, but you must download the rest of the bits from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391

> Until the download package Utilities and Software Development Kit for
>   Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications (Utilities and SDK for SUA) has
>   been installed on the computer, you cannot run or modify UNIX-based
>   scripts and custom UNIX-based applications.

Comment: This is theory. Look at the comments to the question. When trying it all, there is no psxdll.lib anywhere to be found, is there? I tried all of the above (as did the OP) and never found a single psxdll.lib in any of the downloads pointed out above. I think somebody who definitely knows where the relevant .lib files are hidden should shed some light here. Until then, I tend to agree with @IvanKrivyakov that the support has been silently broken.